# Azure storage minimum TLS version 1.2 not enforced in protocol layer

Tags: azure

I read this thread [Minimum TLS Version in Azure Storage Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481490/minimum-tls-version-in-azure-storage-account) and https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/84792 and I was wondering whether there is a way to enforce TLS 1.2 minimum in all the layers so the tools such as ssllab would not be able to user lower versions at all. Unfortunately, those threads do not explain this issue. Does anybody know if there is a way for tls 1.2 to be enforced in protocol layer as well?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The threads you linked indicate that now TLSv1.2 can be enforced on all connections to storage accounts.  Are you asking if there is a way to enforce TLSv1.2 on a connection to an application that accesses the storage account on the backend?

Comment: I mean this fragment - "Because storage account minimum TLS version is enforced at the application layer, tools that attempt to determine TLS/SSL support at the protocol layer will return more TLS/SSL versions supported than the minimum configured version when run against direct storage acccount domains (i.e. contoso.blob.core.windows.net)" - ssllab claims that my app residing in storage account which is configured  with TLS 1.2 minimum is not in fact using 1.2 minimum. When I test via browser I get 400, but is there a way for tests in ssllab to pass with A grade?

Comment: It sounds like you're hosting a static website from a storage account, and when you attempt to enumerate the TLS version/ciphers allowed it's returning TLSv1.0 /1.1 ciphers.  You need it to enforce the TLSv1.2 minimum, which seems reasonable.  I know app services allow you to enforce a minimum TLS version, I'll look at how the static websites served from storage accounts work.

Answer (score 1):

I created a storage account, with the default minimum TLSv1.2, and a static web site.  The web site at testwebsiteca.web.core.windows.net appears to support TLSv1.0/1.1:

[image]

When I scanned the other storage account sites they returned similar results:

```
testwebsiteca.blob.core.windows.net
testwebsiteca.queue.core.windows.net
testwebsiteca.table.core.windows.net
testwebsiteca.file.core.windows.net
```

From rereading the [link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481490/minimum-tls-version-in-azure-storage-account) it looks like, while storage accounts are actually supporting TLSv1.0/1.1, in practical terms they will return an HTTP 400 if someone tries to connect with a lower level TLS.

That's going to cause a tool like ssllab to mark it as supporting a lower TLS version.  It seems strange to me that Microsoft allows the lower TLS connections;  it's enforcing the TLSv1.2 in an odd way that shows up as a red flag to scans.  You might try opening a support ticket with Microsoft.  There doesn't appear to be any way that I can see to get the ssllab scan to give you a green light right now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot. I am going to open a ticket with Microsoft as you suggested and link it here

Answer (score 0):

Here is what microsoft replied:
Azure Storage is a multi-tenant service with a commitment to backwards compatibility. We provide strong controls for storage accounts to opt-in to TLS 1.2 enforcement.

While we encourage all applications to enable TLS 1.2 enforcement, there are a large number of Azure Storage clients that do not yet support the latest security standards. To avoid breaking these and other deployed services, TLS version and cipher suite enforcement is performed in the application layer (HTTP), rather than at the network layer (TCP/TLS).

This enables customers to detect, remediate, and enforce use of specific TLS versions across all their clients. However, it means that port scanning tools like SSL Labs, which do not send HTTP requests to the endpoint, will indicate that legacy TLS versions and cipher suites are supported even if a minimum TLS version is enforced on the account.

This is expected and does not compromise the security of your storage account. Any requests using an insecure TLS version will immediately fail with an HTTP 4xx error. For more information on how to configure TLS enforcement and leverage Azure Policy and Azure Monitor to enforce and monitor this across storage accounts, see  https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/transport-layer-security-configure-minimum-version .

For more information about TLS support and deprecation plans in Azure, please see  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azuretls12/